# Laravel Homestead not logging in

Tags: laravel, ssh

I'm currently trying to setup Laravel Homestead 2.0+. When running `homestead up`, the machine boots up, but then timeouts with the messages:

> default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

The status of the box is running, and I cannot SSH into it.

Looking further into it, when I boot up the VirtualBox GUI, it seems that the box is awaiting login information.

Its asking for a username and password - is this the reason it timeout? Also what is the login information for the box... strange how it doesn't login automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Make sure you have a working internet connection. If not, turn off the router/modem completely while starting vm.